# Double the amount of time until NSTimer's fireDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I'm using an `NSTimer`, and in certain circumstances I want to double how long before the method `NSTimer` calls gets called.

Basically: if I have it set to call every 0.5 seconds, once in awhile I want to delay it so it waits 1.0 seconds (double the time) before the next time it's called.

I'm having a great deal of difficulty implementing this, however. This was my initial attempt:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(timerMethod:) 
                                   userInfo:nil 
                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void)timerMethod:(NSTimer *)timer {
    static int variable = 1;

    switch (variable) {
        case 1:
            self.stopLightLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
            break;
        case 2:
            self.stopLightLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
            break;
        case 3:
            self.stopLightLabel.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
            break;
        case 4: // Stop for twice as long here
            self.stopLightLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];

            NSTimeInterval timeBetweenNowAndFireDate = [timer.fireDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

            // Create a new date that is twice as far in the future in order to give a long pause
            timer.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(timeBetweenNowAndFireDate * 2)];

            break;
        case 5:
            self.stopLightLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            break;
        case 6:
            self.stopLightLabel.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    variable++;
}
```

I try to get the amount of time between *right now* and when the timer will fire. In the example above this should be `0.5`. I then set the `fireDate` to a new value, which is twice the previous.

This does not work, however.

Without that conditional, the timer works normally but obviously does not delay under a certain circumstance (for that circumstance it gets the same amount of time as everything else).

With the conditional, it appears *shorter* even! In fact, it doesn't get longer until I multiply it by around 400 instead of 2!

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why not just add the condition to the called selector to decide if to run or not and then you don't have to fiddle with the timer at all

Comment: What are the actual values you see for the time intervals while debugging this?

Comment: and WHEN are you doing this :) show us a bit more code plz

Comment: @Paul.s Because the `fireDate` instance variable was created for exactly that purpose...

Comment: @Daij-Djan Here's a full project showing it: http://cl.ly/0q0L3R2X2E3y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you call the code to modify the fireDate inside the timerFired method. That's too early. The fireDate is the date when the timer DID fire there.. it isnt updated yet.

one easy fix: wrap it in a dispatch async. that lets the timer return and update its fireDate BEFORE you try to modify it:

fixed code:

```
- (void)timerMethod:(NSTimer *)timer {
    static int variable = 1;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self afterTimerFired:timer];
    }
 }

- (void)afterTimerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    static int variable = 1;        
        switch (variable) {

            case 4: // Stop for twice as long here
                self.stopLightLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                ...
                NSTimeInterval timeBetweenNowAndFireDate = [timer.fireDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
                NSLog(@"%f", timeBetweenNowAndFireDate);
                // Create a new date that is twice as far in the future in order to give a long pause
                timer.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(timeBetweenNowAndFireDate * 2)];
                ...
```

## OR

dont dispatch async and make 
`fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:fire.timeInterval*2]` wich might be even cleaner if possible

Comment: OR dont dispatch async and make fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:fire.timeInterval*2]

Comment: I dont agree as it perfectly predictable. Im moving my code at the next iteration of the runloop -- same as a performSelector:afterDelay:0 is totally predictable and OFTEN used :) -- a dispatch_after that would introduce some random delay would be bad

Comment: I don't disagree that it would work, but I always go through extra pain to ensure that's the only solution before adding a delay to make something work.

Comment: yes, a DELAY is bad as it feels like a hack .. but im not really adding a delay, I move it ALWAYS after the current method call.

Comment: That's a delay as you are delaying execution until the next run loop. But thinking through the problem it seems like the simplest thing that will work

Comment: @Paul.s but go with the OR way .... I guess in this case I would too! :) I wanted to show explicitly why the OPs code didnt work

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that you can't change the fireDate of a running timer. (This is wrong. See the edit below.)

The other poster, Paul.s, had the same idea I did. If you have a timer that fires every .5 seconds, add a BOOL skipThisInterval instance variable to the object that is the timer's target.

Then, in your timer method, if skipThisInterval is true, simply reset `skipThisinterval = FALS`E and return without doing anything else. That way the timer will fire again after another interval has passed and then continue running as before.

Failing that, you'll have to invalidate the running timer, create a new timer that will fire once at your desired end time, and then in the method that timer invokes, create a new repeating timer that goes back to firing on the old interval.

EDIT: I was wrong. You can change the fire date of an "in-flight" timer. (Thanks for Josh Caswell for correcting me on that.)

Even still, if you just want your timer to simply skip it's next firing and keep going, simply adding logic to the method the timer invokes to skip the next firing seems simpler and cleaner than adjusting the fireDate (and the docs say that changing the fire date is relatively expensive.)

Comment: You can indeed change the `fireDate` for a scheduled timer. The docs say "You typically use this method to adjust the firing time of a repeating timer."

Comment: That's the whole point of the `fireDate`, so I'm trying to use that.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, my mistake. Thanks for correcting me. I learned something. That'll teach me to post based on an assumption rather than checking the docs. (voted)

Comment: @DuncanC we might not have read the same docs ^^ modifying the fireDate is better then throwing away and recreating the timer

Comment: @Daij-Djan, I did not propose throwing away the timer. I suggested writing a timer method that simply ignored one firing of the timer and let the timer keep running.

Comment: I was refering to both alternatives you give: a bool I find fragile. you should maybe at least add it to the timer using a category -- and throing it away is not needed.

Comment: BUT I also misread your paragraph 'Even still...' (revoking vote)